# Collection is being changed in another thread before GUI thread is done with it

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm writing a program to record load cell data. The data collecting is done in a separate thread. The collection the data is stored in, is passed back every .5 seconds to the UI where is it displayed in a graph. I'm using a foreach to copy it into a points list for ZedGraph. The problem is that the foreach loop doesn't finish sometimes, before the collection gets updated with new data in the data collection thread. This causes an exception to get thrown.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this problem?

ETA:

```
private void record()
        {
            stopwatch.Reset();
            stopwatch.Start();

            comport.Open();
            comport.DiscardInBuffer();
            comport.DiscardOutBuffer();


            //comport.Write(COMMAND_COLDRESET + Environment.NewLine);
            //comport.Write(COMMAND_CONTINUOUSMODE + "<CR>");
            comport.Write(COMMAND_CONTINUOUSMODE + Environment.NewLine);

            recordingStartTrigger(); //** Fire Recording Started Event

            TimeOut.Start();
            updateTimer.Start();

            this.waitHandleTest.WaitOne(); //** wait for test to end

            TimeOut.Stop();
            updateTimer.Stop();

            comport.sendCommand(COMMAND_COMMANDMODE + Environment.NewLine);
            comport.Close();
            recordingStopTrigger(status); //** Fire Recording Stopped Event

            stopwatch.Stop();
        }


        //***********************************************************************************
        //** Events Handlers


        private void comDataReceived_Handler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            double force = 0;

            TimeOut.Stop();


            string temp = comport.getBuffer(true);
            if (!this.stop)
            {
                //force = Convert.ToDouble(temp);


                if(double.TryParse(temp, out force))
                {
                    report.Readings.Add(new Models.Reading { Time = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, Force = force });
                }
            }
            else
            {

                this.WaitEventTest.Set(); //** triggers the record method to continue and end the test.
            }


            TimeOut.Start(); //** reset TimeOut Timer
        }


    void updateTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        //** fire delagate that GUI will be listening to, to update graph.
        eventNewData(this, new eventArgsNewData(report));

    }
```

Comment: Can you show some sample code?

Comment: You can use fancy tricks like persistent immutable collections or copy-on-write to do this much more nicely.  What operations do you need?

Comment: Can it be done using an observable concurrent collection? Can the UI thread listen for changes to the collection when the collection is being updated in another thread?

Comment: I don't know... I don't know anything about observable concurrent collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this problem is to stop sending the collection to the UI thread.  This is fundamentally unsafe because you are reading from it on one thread while writing on another.  Unless you are using a collection specifically designed for this task it will fail

Here are some possible solutions

1. Use one of the new concurrent collections like `ConcurrentQueue<T>`
2. Pass back a copy of the collection to the UI thread

My choice would be #2.

Comment: I agree with Jared, return a copy of the collection to the UI, don't try to iterate through the collection that is being actively pumped with data.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking maybe passing a copy would work, but I wasn't sure. Also how do I pass a copy back? I'll update my Question with some of my code.

Comment: @TheColonel26 if you are using `List<T>` then just pass back `new List<T>(theOriginalList)`.  Not that this will only fix the enumeration problem.  If you are also mutating the elements in the list on the background thread and reading them from the UI thread you will just run into another variation of this issue

Comment: it's a ICollection because it's part of a Entity Model that gets added to a database when the test is done.